# Generating new Cards based on List of Objects

Tags: list, object, widget, flutter

I have a list of objects, is there a way to loop over a Card widget so that for each object in this list, a new card created with the attributes of this widget of interest.

The following code definitely does not work, it only serves as an illustration to show the logic behind what I am trying to achieve

```
//function declaration and body...
List<CardInfo> list = new List();
for (var i in cardInfo){ //cardInfo is a list of json created previously.
list.add(new CardInfo.fromJson(i));
    print (list); }//tested the list and it contains the objects I want
 return list;
}
```

**...**

```
//my widget{
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Dismissible(
for (i in list){
            child:  new Card(
              child:
              new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
                title: new Text(list(i).field1),//field1 is a string in CardInfo
                subtitle: new Text(list(i).field2),//field2 is a string in CardInfo
```

is this doable by any mean ?

**Update**

I figured out converting each JSON into object and then working with the objects directly, now _loadData() function returns an object on each iteration

```
_loadData() async {
  var url = 'myurl';
  var httpClient  = createHttpClient();
  var response =await httpClient.get(url);
  List cardInfo = JSON.decode(response.body);
  List<CardInfo> list = new List();
  for ( var i in cardInfo){
    var ci = new CardInfo.fromJson(i);

    list.add(new CardInfo.fromJson(i));

  return ci;
  }
  //return list;

}


....
```

So is there a way to set up my class constructor so that it allows me to access the fields of the returned objects ? something like this:

```
title: new Text(new CardInfo(_loadData()).field)
```

**Update 2:**

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new FutureBuilder(
          future: _loadData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> jsonList){
            if (jsonList.hasData==true){
              var cardInfo = jsonList.data[0];//is this right ?
              print (cardInfo); 
              return new Dismissible(
                child: new Column(
                  children:
                  cardInfo.map(
                          (CardInfo info)=>
                      new Card(
                          child: new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
                            title: new Text(info.field),
                            subtitle: new Text("Subtitle"),)

                      ) ), ),....
```

My function is at the top as follows:

```
  _loadData() async {
var url = 'myurl';
var httpClient = createHttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.get(url);
List cardInfo = JSON.decode(response.body);


List<CardInfo> list = new List();
for (var i in cardInfo) {


list.add(new CardInfo.fromJson(i));
}


return list;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Class 'CardInfo' has no instance method 'map'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method to do this. For example:

```
new Column(
  children: list.map(
    (CardInfo info) => new Card(child: new Text(info.field1)),
  ).toList()
)
```

Comment: I tried something else that might be simpler, I am not sure if it possible, but can you please check the updated section and give me your feedback ?

Comment: I tried your solution and I get the following error

(Class '_Future' has no instance method 'map')

Comment: The network code is async so it returns a future. You should save your list to a List in a setState callback, or use FutureBuilder

Comment: I do not understand how to setup FutureBuilder in order to access the fields of the class? list.map should still apply ?

Comment: Remove the return ci statement, uncomment return list. You can now use loadData as the future argument of FutureBuilder. In your builder callback, if the hasData property is true, use the data property of the AsyncSnapshot to get the List.

Comment: Kindly check the update 2 section, I get an error message "Class 'CardInfo' does not have an instance method 'map'"

Comment: It looks like jsonList.data[0] is a CardInfo. Maybe you meant jsonList.data?

Comment: Now I get this error when I try to debug my app, 'The getter 'info' was called on null'

Comment: It looks like it does not link each object in the list with info for some reason.

Comment: I am sorry I got confused, my error was related to my Desmissible key, I have to remove it altogether, and now the json data is inserted in my card. Thank you very much for your great help.