# How to Map Flutter JSON Strings from List?

Tags: json, serialization, dart, flutter

I'm successfully printing my response as String from my YouTube JSON url, but when I try to serialize through the "items" I get the following error `Unhandled exception:
    type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'json' where
      List is from dart:core
      Map is from dart:core`

Here is my code...

```
class CardInfo {
  //Constructor
  String id;
  String description;
  String role;
  //int score;

  CardInfo.fromJson(Map json) {
    this.id = json['vieoId'];
    this.description = json['description'];
    this.role = json['title'];
    //this.score = json['score'];
  }
}

Future getData() async {
    String url = 'YouTube url';
    var httpClient  = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.get(url);
    Map data = JSON.decode(response.body);
    //String ip = data['items'];
    var ci = new CardInfo.fromJson(data['items']);

    //print(data['items']);
    print(ci.id);
    //print(ci.description);
    //print(ci.role);

    if (!mounted) return;


    setState(() {});

  }
```

`print(data['items']` is printing, but `print(ci.id)` or any Card Info variables throws the above error.

**** Log of `print(data)`;

```
{kind: youtube#searchListResponse, etag: "VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/P9wyOxsXEuXOCvj7znCun2-EykU", nextPageToken: CAMQAA, regionCode: US, pageInfo: {totalResults: 1000000, resultsPerPage: 3}, items: [{kind: youtube#searchResult, etag: "VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/Csl1kQhnOsbs0j4_336zJAN176k", id: {kind: youtube#video, videoId: e3pUxU_bE6w}, snippet: {publishedAt: 2017-09-14T09:43:17.000Z, channelId: UCbD8EppRX3ZwJSou-TVo90A, title: [PRISTIN - We Like] KPOP TV Show | M COUNTDOWN 170914 EP.541, description: KPOP Chart Show M COUNTDOWN | EP.541 - PRISTIN - We Like ▷Watch more video clips: http://MCOUNTDOWN-KPOP2017 [Kor Ver.] 프리티 ..., thumbnails: {default: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e3pUxU_bE6w/default.jpg, width: 120, height: 90}, medium: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e3pUxU_bE6w/mqdefault.jpg, width: 320, height: 180}, high: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e3pUxU_bE6w/hqdefault.jpg, width: 480, height: 360}}, channelTitle: Mnet K-POP, liveBroadcastContent: none}}, {kind: youtube#searchResult, etag: "VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/1JCCNBPNbFeusCp_9-pl4i8q5OU", id: {kind: youtube#video, videoId: Cc4hO9RLdl4}, snippet: {publishedAt: 2017-09-14T10:37:29.000Z, channelId: UCbD8EppRX3ZwJSou-TVo90A, title: [EXO - Power] KPOP TV Show | M COUNTDOWN 170914 EP.541, description: KPOP Chart Show M COUNTDOWN | EP.541 - EXO - Power ▷Watch more video clips: http://MCOUNTDOWN-KPOP2017 [Kor Ver.] Power Up! '#EXO' 여기 ..., thumbnails: {default: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cc4hO9RLdl4/default.jpg, width: 120, height: 90}, medium: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cc4hO9RLdl4/mqdefault.jpg, width: 320, height: 180}, high: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cc4hO9RLdl4/hqdefault.jpg, width: 480, height: 360}}, channelTitle: Mnet K-POP, liveBroadcastContent: none}}, {kind: youtube#searchResult, etag: "VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/ZnYC4e5evyfldkM67HsDuV8Yh3E", id: {kind: youtube#video, videoId: BBcOM25wrVo}, snippet: {publishedAt: 2017-08-18T15:21:48.000Z, channelId: UCtFtO4By4czgkYGvEXvJu0A, title: Kpop Banned Dance: MV vs LIVE, description: Kpop Banned Dance: MV vs LIVE Koreas biggest broadcasting companies has strict rules and standards on what lyrics and dances moves can be performed., thumbnails: {default: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BBcOM25wrVo/default.jpg, width: 120, height: 90}, medium: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BBcOM25wrVo/mqdefault.jpg, width: 320, height: 180}, high: {url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BBcOM25wrVo/hqdefault.jpg, width: 480, height: 360}}, channelTitle: Kpop Corn, liveBroadcastContent: none}}]}
```

***  UPDATE WITH FOR LOOP STATEMENT

Here is code for my `for loop` that's returning a `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'` error...

```
Map data = JSON.decode(response);
var videos = data['items'];
for (var items in videos['snippet']){
      print(items);
    }
```

Running a loop through `items in videos` gives me 3 separate entries for the 3 videos I'm looking for - including snippets. Trying to get the individual snippets is failing.  Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe you are passing the `value` of  the `key` `"items"`, which from the look of it is actually a `List` not a `Map`, your constructor should receive a `Map` but instead you are passing a `List`. Hence, you get the error.

Otherwise, can you show me print(data) to see how your database is constructed ?

Comment: @aziza Thank you for the lesson below.  Map = NSDictionary and List = NSArray.  I've noticed that there's an `itar` and `iter` to iterate through a List.; I'm reading documentation on those now.  I've added `print(data)` to my question.  Please help get Maps of titles, videoId's, descriptions, and "medium" thumbnail url's.  Thank you.

Comment: From what I see you are trying to access the values of `snippet` of `items`. So, you need to loop over your data['items'] index by index, and then check when you reach the "snippet" key, and pass this particular map to your class constructor.

Comment: @aziza Attempting to look through `items` to get to my `snippets` threw the above error.  Please review.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like `data['items']` is a `List` (i.e. a JSON Array), not a `Map`.

You can use list comprehension methods to help here:

```
final items = (data['items'] as List).map((i) => new CardInfo.fromJson(i));
for (final item in items) {
  print(item.id);
}
```

Comment: 'data[items]' is also a List, or what SWIFT would call a Dictionary. Can I use a for statement to iterate through 'item's the same way?

Comment: @CharlesJr that is not true, a `Dictionary` is not the same thing as a `List`. They are two different collections. In fact, a `Dictionary` is actually a `Map`. Please read my comment on the question and try to check `print (data['items'])`, you will find that your value for items is actually a `List` of a `Map`, something similar to this `'items': [{..:..},{..:..}....]`

Comment: @matanlurey I'm having issues with my `for loop`.  Please take a look at my updated Question and add it to your answer.

Comment: @matanlurey There is another Array inside my items. 'items': [{'SubItem':[ ]},{'SubItem':[ ]}....]   How should i handle this situation

Comment: I used .toList() at the end to populate properly a list widget.

Answer (score 1):

The following line gives you the `List` of `items`.

```
var videos = data['items'];
```

and you get the error because of this line

```
for(var items in videos['snippet'])
```

In the previous line you think you are iterating on the data inside `snippet`, while in fact, you are trying to iterate on the index 'snippet' inside the list of videos, which does not make sense because iterating over any list happens using integer values `videos[0] , videos [1], videos [2]` .. while you are passing a `String` `'snippet'`

You need first to iterate on your `videos` list item by item (each item is a Map). Store each `Map` in a variable. then you can access the values of `snippet` by `myMap['snippet']`

```
    Map data = JSON.decode(response);
    var videos = data['items']; //returns a List of Maps
    for (var items in videos){ //iterate over the list
    Map myMap = items; //store each map 
    print(myMap['snippet']);
        }
```

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Great!  Now I have 3 individual snippets which I'm assuming I can run similar maps to and index on my Card widgets.  I believe you have a similar SO question that I can draw from.

Comment: Yes, you can now pass the snippet to your class constructor, you might want to store their data outside the loop first. Glad it is working for you.

Comment: I believe this [what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214524/generating-new-cards-based-on-list-of-objects)

Comment: @CharlesJr I have added more details about why did you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I would Love to share this and some expert can also please improve this codes, After alot of hours have battle with it.

**Model Class**

```
class Testimony{
    String fullname;
   String testimony;

   Testimony({this.fullname,
     this.testimony}); 

    factory Testimony.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Testimony(
      fullname: json['fullname'] as String,
       testimony: json['testimony'] as String,  
         );

         }
```

**API CLASS**

```
List<Testimony> ToListandMap (String responseBody) {
 Map data = json.decode(responseBody);
    var videos = data['testimonies']; //returns a List of Maps
  final casting =  videos.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
   return casting.map<Testimony>((json) => Testimony.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }

Future<List<Testimony>> fetchTestimonies(http.Client client) async {
       final response = await client.get('https://tryjambcbt.com/api/testimonies');

         return ToList(response.body);
         }
```

**MainWidget for UI**

```
FutureBuilder<List<Testimony>>(
    future: fetchTestimonies(http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? TestimonyList(testimony: snapshot.data)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
```

**Widget**

```
class TestimonyList extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Testimony> testimony;

TestimonyList({Key key, this.testimony}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    itemCount: testimony.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Text(testimony[index].testimony)
       );
      },
    );
   }
  }
```